# How do you extract header files from a private framework on OS X?

Tags: macos

I've tried [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) and [class-dump-x](http://iphone.freecoder.org/classdump_en.html), but neither works on `CoreSymbolication.framework` on Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.2)

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework

Are there are any other ways to retrieve the headers for this framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CoreSymbolication is not written in Objective-C but in C++. That’s why class-dump does not work. You can use

```
nm /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/CoreSymbolication | c++filt
```

to look at the symbols defined in CoreSymbolication. They are a little difficult to read because of heavy template usage.

Alas, for C++, it’s not possible to generate full header information out of the executable.